# what kind of an array will mysql_fetch_array($result) fetch?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch values from a table in a MySQL database into PHP.

What kind of array will `mysql_fetch_array($result)` return? Associative or numeric?

Comment: Easily answered by testing it out yourself or checking [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php), right?

Comment: did you try a var_dump ?

Answer (score 4):

> array mysql_fetch_array ( resource $result [, int $result_type =
>   MYSQL_BOTH ] )

It depends on the second parameter which is default `MYSQL_BOTH` and could be `MYSQL_ASSOC`, `MYSQL_NUM`, and `MYSQL_BOTH`.

More info about [mysql_fetch_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php).

Answer (score 3):

From the manual:

> [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) — Fetch a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both

Comment: Did you read the manual yourself? Compare with xdazz's answer

Comment: @WesleyMurch if that's the case, I agree. Because it's typo and it's my fault.

Answer (score 1):

It returns an array with both numeric and string indexes.